Ubuntu. Openvpn not assign ip addr and routes to tun a
ubuntu - 20.04
openvpn - 2.4.12
openvpn config
dev tun
proto tcp
remote ...
client
resolv-retry infinite
persist-key
persist-tun
cipher AES-256-CBC
verb 3
key-direction 1
remote-cert-tls server
When i ran openvpn via command line
i see in the log next
Sun Jun  9 15:09:52 2024 /sbin/ip link set dev tun0 up mtu 1500
Sun Jun  9 15:09:52 2024 /sbin/ip addr add dev tun0 192.168.--.--/25 broadcast 192.168.90.127
Sun Jun  9 15:09:52 2024 /sbin/ip route add 89.108.--.--/32 via 192.168.--.--
Sun Jun  9 15:09:52 2024 /sbin/ip route add 172.10.--.--/24 via 192.168.--.--

But if i check ifconfig then i see that ap not applied to the tun
tun0: flags=4305<UP,POINTOPOINT,RUNNING,NOARP,MULTICAST>  mtu 1500
        inet6 fe80::fd92:92cd:bd13:d553  prefixlen 64  scopeid 0x20<link>
        unspec 00-00-00-00-00-00-00-00-00-00-00-00-00-00-00-00  txqueuelen 100  (UNSPEC)
        RX packets 0  bytes 0 (0.0 B)
        RX errors 0  dropped 0  overruns 0  frame 0
        TX packets 4  bytes 228 (228.0 B)
        TX errors 0  dropped 0 overruns 0  carrier 0  collisions 0


If then i add manyaly ip and route from openvpn logs then it appears in ifconfig output and vpn works fine.
Can anybody help? Why ip address not applied via openvpn config only for manual. And intersting that log says me that this ip was applied but in reais it was not.
I also tried to add update-resove-conf to the script but it is not changed anything.
And recently my vpn works find without it

In syslog found this
Jun  9 16:54:34 --: Unnecessary job for /sys/subsystem/net/devices/tun0 was removed.
Jun  9 16:54:34 --: Started Netscript ifup for tun0.


Then check that network-script may be cause of this issue.
Install ifupdown (it also remove netscript) and now tun accquring the ip and set routes.
